# Database-First & Error: Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a problem with the project I am working on. On POST:Edit, it saves my changes. On POST:Create, I receive this error: "Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values."

So I did what my teachers taught us in College: I just Googled it. The answers however were suggesting to change the ModelBuilder-fluent API. I do not think this would be inappropriate since I use Database-First approach (It says it is only for Code-First) **AND** my Save is functional in Edit. Since I wanted to work with ViewModels, I followed this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/702890/MVC-Entity-Framework-and-Many-to-Many-Relation). I even found and posted a solution for the tutorial about the Create method to help me with my problem. Please help me. I am about to throw my computer out of the window. Which is kind of complicated because they are made of tempered glass.

So here's the metadata for my model (with minimal data annotation for readability sake:

```
public partial class Employe
{
    sealed class Metadata
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdEmploye { get; set; }


        public string NomEmploye { get; set; }


        public string PrenomEmploye { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("TitreEmploye_IdTitre")]            
        public int IdTitre { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("Departement_IdDepartement")]            
        public int IdDepartement { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("Employe_IdSuperviseur")]            
        public int IdSuperviseur { get; set; }


        public System.DateTime DateEmbauche { get; set; }


        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateDepart { get; set; }


        public string StatutEmploye { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("Employeur_IdEmployeur")]            
        public int IdEmployeur { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("Localisation_IdLocalisation")]            
        public int IdLocalisation { get; set; }


        public string Langue { get; set; }


        public Nullable<bool> CarteAcces { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("TelephoneBureau_IdTelephoneBureau")]            
        public Nullable<int> IdTelephoneBureau { get; set; }


        public Nullable<bool> CarteAffaire { get; set; }


        public string AdresseCourriel { get; set; }


        public bool CodeAlarme { get; set; }


        public System.DateTime DateNaissance { get; set; }


        public Nullable<bool> IsSuperviseur { get; set; }


        public Nullable<bool> IsActif { get; set; }
    }
}
```

}

Here's my problematic(?) model:

```
public partial class Employe
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Employe()
    {
        this.AccesApplicatif1 = new HashSet<AccesApplicatif>();
        this.TelephoneCellulaire1 = new HashSet<TelephoneCellulaire>();
        this.CleBatiment1 = new HashSet<CleBatiment>();
        this.EquipementInfo = new HashSet<EquipementInfo>();
        this.GroupeSecurite1 = new HashSet<GroupeSecurite>();
        this.VehiculeCompagnie1 = new HashSet<VehiculeCompagnie>();
        this.Employe1 = new HashSet<Employe>();
    }

    public int IdEmploye { get; set; }
    public string NomEmploye { get; set; }
    public string PrenomEmploye { get; set; }
    public int IdTitre { get; set; }
    public int IdDepartement { get; set; }
    public int IdSuperviseur { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateEmbauche { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateDepart { get; set; }
    public string StatutEmploye { get; set; }
    public int IdEmployeur { get; set; }
    public int IdLocalisation { get; set; }
    public string Langue { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> CarteAcces { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdTelephoneBureau { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> CarteAffaire { get; set; }
    public string AdresseCourriel { get; set; }
    public bool CodeAlarme { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateNaissance { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsSuperviseur { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsActif { get; set; }

    public virtual Departement Departement { get; set; }
    public virtual Employeur Employeur { get; set; }
    public virtual Localisation Localisation { get; set; }
    public virtual TelephoneBureau TelephoneBureau { get; set; }
    public virtual TitreEmploye TitreEmploye { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<AccesApplicatif> AccesApplicatif1 { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<TelephoneCellulaire> TelephoneCellulaire1 { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<CleBatiment> CleBatiment1 { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<EquipementInfo> EquipementInfo { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<GroupeSecurite> GroupeSecurite1 { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<VehiculeCompagnie> VehiculeCompagnie1 { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Employe> Employe1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Employe Employe2 { get; set; }

    public string NomSuperviseur
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", PrenomEmploye, NomEmploye);
        }
    }
}
```

As I said, since I wanted to work with ViewModels, here's the culprit:

```
public partial class EmployeVM
{        
    public Employe Employe { get; set; } //Employe


    public string NomEmploye { get; set; } //Employe


    public string PrenomEmploye { get; set; } //Employe


    public DateTime DateNaissance { get; set; } //Employe


    public string Langue { get; set; } //Employe


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////        
    public IEnumerable<Titre> Titres { get; set; } //TitreEmploye
    public class Titre
    {
        public string description { get; set; } //TitreEmploye
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////       
    public IEnumerable<Departement> Departements { get; set; } //Departement
    public class Departement
    {
        public string description { get; set; } //Departement
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////       
    public IEnumerable<Superviseur> Superviseurs { get; set; } //Employe
    public class Superviseur
    {
        public string nomSuperviseur { get; set; } //Employe
    }


    public string StatutEmploye { get; set; } //Employe


    public DateTime DateEmbauche { get; set; } //Employe


    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateDepart { get; set; } //Employe


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////        
    public IEnumerable<Employeur> Employeurs { get; set; } //Employeur
    public class Employeur
    {
        public string nomEmployeur { get; set; } //Employeur
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////       
    public IEnumerable<Localisation> Localisations { get; set; } //Localisation
    public class Localisation
    {
        public string description { get; set; } //Localisation
    }


    public bool CarteAcces { get; set; } //Employe


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////        
    public IEnumerable<TelephoneBureau> TelephoneBureaux { get; set; } //TelephoneBureau
    public class TelephoneBureau
    {
        public string extension { get; set; } //TelephoneBureau
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////       
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllTelephoneCellulaires { get; set; } //TelephoneCellulaire        
    private List<int> _selectedTelephoneCellulaires;
    public List<int> SelectedTelephoneCellulaires
    {
        get
        {
            if (_selectedTelephoneCellulaires == null)
            {
                _selectedTelephoneCellulaires = Employe.TelephoneCellulaire1.Select(m => m.IdTelephoneCellulaire).ToList();
            }
            return _selectedTelephoneCellulaires;
        }
        set { _selectedTelephoneCellulaires = value; }
    }


    public bool CarteAffaire { get; set; } //Employe


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////        
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllEquipementInformatiques { get; set; } //EquipementInfo
    private List<int> _selectedEquipementInformatiques;
    public List<int> SelectedEquipementInformatiques
    {
        get
        {
            if (_selectedEquipementInformatiques == null)
            {
                _selectedEquipementInformatiques = Employe.EquipementInfo.Select(m => m.IdEquipementInfo).ToList();
            }
            return _selectedEquipementInformatiques;
        }
        set { _selectedEquipementInformatiques = value; }
    }


    public string AdresseCourriel { get; set; } //Employe


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////      
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllGroupeSecurites { get; set; } //GroupeSecurite
    private List<int> _selectedGroupeSecurites;
    public List<int> SelectedGroupeSecurites
    {
        get
        {
            if (_selectedGroupeSecurites == null)
            {
                _selectedGroupeSecurites = Employe.GroupeSecurite1.Select(m => m.IdGroupeSecurite).ToList();
            }
            return _selectedGroupeSecurites;
        }
        set { _selectedGroupeSecurites = value; }
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////       
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllAccesApplicatifs { get; set; } //AccesApplicatif
    private List<int> _selectedAccesApplicatifs;
    public List<int> SelectedAccesApplicatifs
    {
        get
        {
            if (_selectedAccesApplicatifs == null)
            {
                _selectedAccesApplicatifs = Employe.AccesApplicatif1.Select(m => m.IdAccesApplicatif).ToList();
            }
            return _selectedAccesApplicatifs;
        }
        set { _selectedAccesApplicatifs = value; }
    }


    public bool CodeAlarme { get; set; } //Employe


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////       
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllCleBatiments { get; set; } //CleBatiment
    private List<int> _selectedCleBatiments;
    public List<int> SelectedCleBatiments
    {
        get
        {
            if (_selectedCleBatiments == null)
            {
                _selectedCleBatiments = Employe.CleBatiment1.Select(m => m.IdCleBatiment).ToList();
            }
            return _selectedCleBatiments;
        }
        set { _selectedCleBatiments = value; }
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////       
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllVehiculeCompagnies { get; set; } //VehiculeCompagnie
    private List<int> _selectedVehiculeCompagnies;
    public List<int> SelectedVehiculeCompagnies
    {
        get
        {
            if (_selectedVehiculeCompagnies == null)
            {
                _selectedVehiculeCompagnies = Employe.VehiculeCompagnie1.Select(m => m.IdVehiculeCompagnie).ToList();
            }
            return _selectedVehiculeCompagnies;
        }
        set { _selectedVehiculeCompagnies = value; }
    }


    public bool IsSuperviseur { get; set; } //Employe


    public bool IsActif { get; set; } //Employe

    public EmployeVM()
    {
        AllTelephoneCellulaires = new List<SelectListItem>();
        AllEquipementInformatiques = new List<SelectListItem>();
        AllGroupeSecurites = new List<SelectListItem>();
        AllAccesApplicatifs = new List<SelectListItem>();
        AllCleBatiments = new List<SelectListItem>();
        AllVehiculeCompagnies = new List<SelectListItem>();                    
    }
}
```

And here's the Create part of my Controller (I KNOW I will have to add some methods to comply to DRY, but for now, that's what it is:

```
// GET: Employes/Create
    //[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get), ImportModelStateFromTempData]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var employeView = new EmployeVM();

        //Population pour les ListBoxFor
        var allTelephoneCellulaireActifList = db.TelephoneCellulaireActif.ToList();
        ViewBag.AllTelephoneCellulaires = allTelephoneCellulaireActifList.Select(o => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = o.Description,
            Value = o.IdTelephoneCellulaire.ToString()
        });
        var allEquipementInfoActifList = db.EquipementInfoActif.ToList();
        ViewBag.AllEquipementInformatiques = allEquipementInfoActifList.Select(o => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = o.Description,
            Value = o.IdEquipementInfo.ToString()
        });
        var allGroupeSecuriteList = db.GroupeSecurite.ToList();
        ViewBag.AllGroupeSecurites = allGroupeSecuriteList.Select(o => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = o.Description,
            Value = o.IdGroupeSecurite.ToString()
        });
        var allAccesApplicatifActifList = db.AccesApplicatifActif.ToList();
        ViewBag.AllAccesApplicatifs = allAccesApplicatifActifList.Select(o => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = o.Description,
            Value = o.IdAccesApplicatif.ToString()
        });
        var allCleBatimentList = db.CleBatiment.ToList();
        ViewBag.AllCleBatiments = allCleBatimentList.Select(o => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = o.Description,
            Value = o.IdCleBatiment.ToString()
        });
        var allVehiculeCompagnieActifList = db.VehiculeCompagnieActif.ToList();
        ViewBag.AllVehiculeCompagnies = allVehiculeCompagnieActifList.Select(o => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = o.DescriptionVehicule,
            Value = o.IdVehiculeCompagnie.ToString()
        });

        //Zero-or-One-to-Many relationships
        List<TitreEmployeActif> ListeTitreEmployeActif = db.TitreEmployeActif.OrderBy(titre => titre.Description).ToList();
        ViewBag.IdTitre = new SelectList(ListeTitreEmployeActif, "IdTitre", "Description");

        List<Departement> ListeDepartement = db.Departement.OrderBy(departement => departement.Description).ToList();
        ViewBag.IdDepartement = new SelectList(ListeDepartement, "IdDepartement", "Description");

        List<EmployeSuperviseurActif> ListeEmployeSuperviseurActif = db.EmployeSuperviseurActif.OrderBy(sup => sup.PrenomNom).ToList();
        ViewBag.IdSuperviseur = new SelectList(ListeEmployeSuperviseurActif, "IdEmploye", "PrenomNom");

        List<Employeur> ListeEmployeur = db.Employeur.OrderBy(employeur => employeur.NomEmployeur).ToList();
        ViewBag.IdEmployeur = new SelectList(ListeEmployeur, "IdEmployeur", "NomEmployeur");

        List<Localisation> ListeLocalisation = db.Localisation.OrderBy(localisation => localisation.Description).ToList();
        ViewBag.IdLocalisation = new SelectList(ListeLocalisation, "IdLocalisation", "Description");

        List<TelephoneBureauActif> ListeTelephoneBureauActif = db.TelephoneBureauActif.OrderBy(phone => phone.Extension).ToList();
        ViewBag.IdTelephoneBureau = new SelectList(ListeTelephoneBureauActif, "IdTelephoneBureau", "Extension");

        return View();
    }

    // POST: Employes/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, 
    // for more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(EmployeVM employeView)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var obj in ModelState.Values)
            {
                foreach (var error in obj.Errors)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error.ErrorMessage))
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERROR WHY = " + error.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var employeToAdd = db.Employe
                .Include(e => e.TelephoneCellulaire1)
                .Include(e => e.EquipementInfo)
                .Include(e => e.GroupeSecurite1)
                .Include(e => e.AccesApplicatif1)
                .Include(e => e.CleBatiment1)
                .Include(e => e.VehiculeCompagnie1)
                .First();

            if (TryUpdateModel(employeToAdd, "Employe", new string[] { "IdEmploye", "NomEmploye", "PrenomEmploye", "IdTitre", "IdDepartement", "IdSuperviseur", "DateEmbauche", "DateDepart", "StatutEmploye", "IdEmployeur", "IdLocalisation", "Langue", "CarteAcces", "TelephoneCellulaire", "IdTelephoneBureau", "CarteAffaire", "EquipementInformatique", "AdresseCourriel", "GroupeSecurite", "AccesApplicatif", "CodeAlarme", "CleBatiment", "VehiculeCompagnie", "DateNaissance", "IsSuperviseur", "IsActif" }))
            {
                var updatedTelephoneCellulaires = new HashSet<int>(employeView.SelectedTelephoneCellulaires);
                var updatedEquipementInformatiques = new HashSet<int>(employeView.SelectedEquipementInformatiques);
                var updatedGroupeSecurites = new HashSet<int>(employeView.SelectedGroupeSecurites);
                var updatedAccesApplicatifs = new HashSet<int>(employeView.SelectedAccesApplicatifs);
                var updatedCleBatiments = new HashSet<int>(employeView.SelectedCleBatiments);
                var updatedVehiculeCompagnies = new HashSet<int>(employeView.SelectedVehiculeCompagnies);

                //Prochaine ligne db.TelephoneCellulaire1 !!! ou db.TelephoneCellulaireActif ???  Check readonly
                foreach (TelephoneCellulaire telephone in db.TelephoneCellulaire)
                {
                    if (!updatedTelephoneCellulaires.Contains(telephone.IdTelephoneCellulaire))
                    {
                        employeToAdd.TelephoneCellulaire1.Remove(telephone);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        employeToAdd.TelephoneCellulaire1.Add(telephone);
                    }
                }
                foreach (EquipementInfo equipement in db.EquipementInfo)
                {
                    if (!updatedEquipementInformatiques.Contains(equipement.IdEquipementInfo))
                    {
                        employeToAdd.EquipementInfo.Remove(equipement);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        employeToAdd.EquipementInfo.Add(equipement);
                    }
                }
                foreach (GroupeSecurite groupe in db.GroupeSecurite)
                {
                    if (!updatedGroupeSecurites.Contains(groupe.IdGroupeSecurite))
                    {
                        employeToAdd.GroupeSecurite1.Remove(groupe);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        employeToAdd.GroupeSecurite1.Add(groupe);
                    }
                }
                foreach (AccesApplicatif acces in db.AccesApplicatif)
                {
                    if (!updatedAccesApplicatifs.Contains(acces.IdAccesApplicatif))
                    {
                        employeToAdd.AccesApplicatif1.Remove(acces);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        employeToAdd.AccesApplicatif1.Add(acces);
                    }
                }
                foreach (CleBatiment cle in db.CleBatiment)
                {
                    if (!updatedCleBatiments.Contains(cle.IdCleBatiment))
                    {
                        employeToAdd.CleBatiment1.Remove(cle);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        employeToAdd.CleBatiment1.Add(cle);
                    }
                }
                foreach (VehiculeCompagnie vehicule in db.VehiculeCompagnie)
                {
                    if (!updatedVehiculeCompagnies.Contains(vehicule.IdVehiculeCompagnie))
                    {
                        employeToAdd.VehiculeCompagnie1.Remove(vehicule);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        employeToAdd.VehiculeCompagnie1.Add(vehicule);
                    }
                }
            }
            db.Employe.Add(employeToAdd);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }                    

        var allTelephoneCellulaireActifList = db.TelephoneCellulaireActif.ToList();
        ViewBag.AllTelephoneCellulaires = allTelephoneCellulaireActifList.Select(o => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = o.Description,
            Value = o.IdTelephoneCellulaire.ToString()
        });
        var allEquipementInfoActifList = db.EquipementInfoActif.ToList();
        ViewBag.AllEquipementInformatiques = allEquipementInfoActifList.Select(o => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = o.Description,
            Value = o.IdEquipementInfo.ToString()
        });
        var allGroupeSecuriteList = db.GroupeSecurite.ToList();
        ViewBag.AllGroupeSecurites = allGroupeSecuriteList.Select(o => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = o.Description,
            Value = o.IdGroupeSecurite.ToString()
        });
        var allAccesApplicatifActifList = db.AccesApplicatifActif.ToList();
        ViewBag.AllAccesApplicatifs = allAccesApplicatifActifList.Select(o => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = o.Description,
            Value = o.IdAccesApplicatif.ToString()
        });
        var allCleBatimentList = db.CleBatiment.ToList();
        ViewBag.AllCleBatiments = allCleBatimentList.Select(o => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = o.Description,
            Value = o.IdCleBatiment.ToString()
        });
        var allVehiculeCompagnieActifList = db.VehiculeCompagnieActif.ToList();
        ViewBag.AllVehiculeCompagnies = allVehiculeCompagnieActifList.Select(o => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = o.DescriptionVehicule,
            Value = o.IdVehiculeCompagnie.ToString()
        });

        //Zero-or-One-to-Many relationships
        List<TitreEmployeActif> ListeTitreEmployeActif = db.TitreEmployeActif.OrderBy(titre => titre.Description).ToList();
        ViewBag.IdTitre = new SelectList(ListeTitreEmployeActif, "IdTitre", "Description");

        List<Departement> ListeDepartement = db.Departement.OrderBy(departement => departement.Description).ToList();
        ViewBag.IdDepartement = new SelectList(ListeDepartement, "IdDepartement", "Description");

        List<EmployeSuperviseurActif> ListeEmployeSuperviseurActif = db.EmployeSuperviseurActif.OrderBy(sup => sup.PrenomNom).ToList();
        ViewBag.IdSuperviseur = new SelectList(ListeEmployeSuperviseurActif, "IdEmploye", "PrenomNom");

        List<Employeur> ListeEmployeur = db.Employeur.OrderBy(employeur => employeur.NomEmployeur).ToList();
        ViewBag.IdEmployeur = new SelectList(ListeEmployeur, "IdEmployeur", "NomEmployeur");

        List<Localisation> ListeLocalisation = db.Localisation.OrderBy(localisation => localisation.Description).ToList();
        ViewBag.IdLocalisation = new SelectList(ListeLocalisation, "IdLocalisation", "Description");

        List<TelephoneBureauActif> ListeTelephoneBureauActif = db.TelephoneBureauActif.OrderBy(phone => phone.Extension).ToList();
        ViewBag.IdTelephoneBureau = new SelectList(ListeTelephoneBureauActif, "IdTelephoneBureau", "Extension");

        return View(employeView);
    }
```

And just to complete the picture, an extract from Create.cshtml:

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AllEquipementInformatiques, "Équipements informatiques", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedEquipementInformatiques, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AllEquipementInformatiques, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Speaking about a picture, here's a little capture of one of my Many-to-Many table, with data entered with Edit:

[Employe_VehiculeCompagnie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH7hY.png)

The thing to know (and I think it might be part of the problem) is: all of the 6 Many-To-Many relationships are optional. But even when I try to create a new Employe with at least one item in each of the 6 Many-to-Many field, it throws that error. And it still works in Edit. Questions: why this error is thrown and how can I make my app works? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
Should I add this? One of my join table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employe_GroupeSecurite] (
[IdEmploye]        INT NOT NULL,
[IdGroupeSecurite] INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdEmploye] ASC, [IdGroupeSecurite] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Employe_GroupeSecurite_Employe] FOREIGN KEY ([IdEmploye]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employe] ([IdEmploye]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Employe_GroupeSecurite_GroupeSecurite] FOREIGN KEY ([IdGroupeSecurite]) REFERENCES [dbo].[GroupeSecurite] ([IdGroupeSecurite])
```

Now what?

Comment: looks like dependency issue and your foreign keys are not nullable which means you have to provide the keys when adding new record but can make foreign keys nullable just for testing?

Comment: Seems that all foreign key integer properties should using `Nullable<int>` type, e.g. `public int? IdTitre { get; set; }`. The error often occurs when an object containing value-type FK properties mapped to another entity and setting FK properties incorrectly to default value (0) instead of `null`, causing EF to find a PK of "0" in another entity which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! Here's my solution, in case someone else tumbles with the same problem.

For some strange reason, Visual Studio added a '1' at the end of some of my Many-to-Many tables name. Entity Framework did not like it (neither did I), so I renamed them in my model:

Example:

```
public Employe()
{
    this.AccesApplicatif1 = new HashSet<AccesApplicatif>();
    this.TelephoneCellulaire1 = new HashSet<TelephoneCellulaire>();
    this.CleBatiment1 = new HashSet<CleBatiment>();
    this.EquipementInfo = new HashSet<EquipementInfo>();
    this.GroupeSecurite1 = new HashSet<GroupeSecurite>();
    this.VehiculeCompagnie1 = new HashSet<VehiculeCompagnie>();
    this.Employe1 = new HashSet<Employe>();
}
```

Became:

```
this.AccesApplicatif = new HashSet<AccesApplicatif>();
this.TelephoneCellulaire = new HashSet<TelephoneCellulaire>();
this.CleBatiment = new HashSet<CleBatiment>();
this.EquipementInfo = new HashSet<EquipementInfo>();
this.GroupeSecurite = new HashSet<GroupeSecurite>();
this.VehiculeCompagnie = new HashSet<VehiculeCompagnie>();
this.Employe1 = new HashSet<Employe>();
```

Visual Studio was intelligent enough to rename them in pretty much everything, except in my Entities.edmx, Views and my Metadata. I took great care of it and now, verything work like a charm. I still don't understand why I was able to Edit my employes though...